# Stepwise description of file execution in Windows

Tags: windows, operating-system, executable, execution, low-level

What happens, at low-level (stepwise) when a program is executed in windows. In other words the processes that take place from clicking a file to actually reaching execution.

Are you aware of any resources that might cover this topic in-depth?

Comment: read Windows Internals by mark russinovich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest reading [this two part MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985992.aspx) on the Win32 Portable Executable file format.  It describes all the different parts of the file which gives you a lot of information about what has to happen in order to load and run the executable file.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) on the PE format also contains useful info.